# How can I set up a bind that mutes voice chat and says something to my teammates?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to create a bind to mute the voice chat, but also tell in chat whether I muted them or not. The only information I can find on toggling is the toggle commands:
`bind <key> <command> 0 1`

I tried doing `bind k "toggle voice_enable;say Silent Mode: " "on" "off"`, but it did not work.

So I want this (`bind k "toggle voice_enable;`) to say one of these two messages:

`"say -*- Silent Mode -*- Player(s) Muted "`

and

`"say -*- Silent Mode -*- Player(s) Un-Muted "`

How can I do it?

Comment: I'd recommend using "say_team" if you usually play on competitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggling between commands that don't involve a simple 1 and 0 is a bit tricky, but all it requires is the use of a few `alias` commands. Here's a working example of what you want:

> bind k toggleVoice;
>   alias toggleVoice "disableVoice";
>   alias disableVoice "alias toggleVoice enableVoice; voice_enable 0; say Silent mode ON";
>   alias enableVoice "alias toggleVoice disableVoice; voice_enable 1; say Silent mode OFF";

Here's what this is doing:

1. Bind k to the custom command `toggleVoice` that is created in the next step.
2. Use `alias` to create a custom command named `toggleVoice` that runs the custom command `disableVoice` created in the next step.
3. Use `alias` to create a custom command named `disableVoice` that alters step 2 to make `toggleVoice` run the custom command `enableVoice` next time, disable voice transmission, and print "Silent mode ON" in chat.
4. Use `alias` to create a custom command named `enableVoice` that alters step 2 to make `toggleVoice` run the custom command `disableVoice` next time, enable voice transmission, and print "Silent mode OFF" in chat.

Basically we're binding a key to an alias that calls other aliases that alter it while also doing what you need in-game. Note that you'll need to add these to your autoexec.cfg file (or whatever file you set to auto-run when the game starts up) or else you'll have to enter these commands every time.

Comment: I can confirm that this works pretty well. [See this answer if you want to know how autoexec works and how you can create one.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152890/what-is-this-autoexec-cfg-and-what-does-it-do/152891#152891)

Comment: The chat part should probably be say_team so that the other team doesn't use the information against you.